# Can't launch GeoServer on my Mac

Tags: geoserver, java, mac, tomcat

Starting my career as a GIS dev, I'm dealing with problems on GeoServer. I have jdk version 1.8.0_402 installed on my MacBook. I'm using Tomcat 10.0.8, the last version launched which supports JDK version 8 correctly installed, and I downloaded the GeoServer 2.25, which is the last version supporting jdk version 8.
I'm saving the GeoServer .war file on Tomcat web folder, as recommended.

Deploying the GeoServer war file on my Tomcat Web Application Manager I'm getting the follow message:

> FAIL - Application at context path [/geoserver] could not be started

[image: Application at context path [/geoserver] could not be started]

How can I fix this?

Comment: How big is your geoserver war?

Comment: Geoserver dropped support for java 8 from version 2.23. Don't know if that can cause your problem, but I wouldn't waste any time trying to get 2.25 work with java 8.